# How one contact key has multiple device id in Mobile Push

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilestudio

Can someone explain how multiple device id are linked to the same contact Key? That is how the device id's are generated. In my current Org, I have a Contact where it has 5 different deviceid and whenever we send out the notification, 3 of them receive it and the other two - 1 one is opted out and the other one gets errored out.

Can you explain how & when these device ids are getting generated for the same contact key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `deviceId` is a randomly generated UUID created at the time the SDK is first initialized. It is common for users, especially developers who install/uninstall frequently, to have multiple devices associated to their contact.

The `deviceId` will remain static except in the case where the user clears local data, factory resets their device, or obviously, when they uninstall the application.

Comment: Thank You, @Bill Mote